# How should a C library manage errors?

Tags: c, libraries, errno

I’m creating my own C library and I came across a dilemma.

What value should library function return?

Should I have my own errno variable, and then functions return 0 for success and -1 for failure and set errno to the specific error? (like most of libc functions do).

Or should I have an enum containing all the error codes and then every function returns the specific error number?

On the one hand I see the first method (errno) being used in lots of libraries, on the other hand I don’t see why a function returning int should waste its entire 4 bytes of return code for just 0 and -1 and use another global variable to specify the error? Why not return the error number directly?

I would like to get a better sense of why libraries use errno? I might be missing something here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "return code for just 0 and -1". Which functions are you referencing in particular? Many of the standard C functions return something else on success and only return -1 or some other error indicator on failure. In those cases it arguably makes sense to have a seperate `errno` so as to give the function a full range of return values for non-error reporting.

Comment: It is the ultimate opinion based question.

Comment: Important thing is you should have a consistent convention in all your library functions, rest is up to you.

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based to say that global `errno` variable is horrible way to do error handling.

Comment: @user694733 That is your opinion.

Comment: @user694733 `errno` nowadays usually isn't really a global, but a thread-local variable.

Comment: @kaylum I think it’s strange that a function can either return a value, let’s say char*, or a failure code (NULL) and then set another errno variable to specify the error. Why not have the char* variable as an out parameter for the function, and return error code specifying the actual error from the function.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience of embedded software development (mostly bare-metal and low-level), `errno`is not used very often.

I've been usually working on libraries whose functions return 0 for success and a positive value for errors. The different error values may be defined as an enum, as macros or whatever.

The fact that 0 is the value for success make the error management convenient:

```
if ( function(...) )
{
    ... // handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `errno` method has the advantage, that you only need *one* return value signaling failure (especially useful, when the range of the return value is largely used).

Furthermore, it allows to have functions like `perror()`, that use `errno` implicitly.

It is not advisable to mix both variants (-1/errno vs. directly returning error codes), because the error handling is very individual for each function then.